# I have written a Java program with 10000 lines of code in a class. Is it normal?

Tags: java, swt, frontend, jface

I have written front-end of my application in SWT/JFace. It working well but problem is that all of the front-end goes in a few classes and some classes grow more than 10000 lines of code. Tell me is it normal to have classes in Java with more than thousands of lines of code or how can I reduce it?

Comment: Depends if you're maintaining the code itself or the tool generating the code...

Comment: you can reduce it by creating subclasses, and composition, rather than cramming everything in one single file

Comment: Not ideal I suppose, but what does it do?..

Comment: #miguelmpn Program is business sector application to handle all the transaction in a medium sized company.

Comment: GUI works in tabs, each task opens a new tab. Code of all tabs go in a single class. How can I split that code in compositions or subclasses?

Answer (score 4):

It is definitely not good practice to have such huge classes and a signal to better refactor your code. See http://clean-code-developer.com for a clean code guideline.

Comment: @All. Thanks, corrected it.

Comment: "Files longer than 2000 lines are cumbersome and should be avoided".

[Java Code Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

You can't judge a java class on  lines number. No standard can tell you about the preferable number of code lines. 
The important thing to keep in mind is that classes **should be designed according to proper OOP design** using: encapsulation, polymorphism ...etc and java best practices. 
But a Class with >1000 lines of code it's probably unreadable and have a bad loosely coupled approach. 
If your number of code line start to increase quickly try to optimize your code and use dedicated design pattern like Strategy pattern and many others one.